# Convert a table of strings to int with scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i've got a big file called World.json which contains a big amount of data of all the countries around the world. I've been using a list to show all the data in a table. I want to sort all values in order. But the problem is that all my **int values are strings** in world.json. I know that i need to use parseInt to make it work but tried everything without any success

just and example of code in
**World.js**

```
"Country": [
{
  "Code": "AFG",
  "Name": "Afghanistan",
  "Continent": "Asia",
  "Region": "Southern and Central Asia",
  "SurfaceArea": "652090.00",
  "IndepYear": "1919",
  "Population": "22720000",
  "LifeExpectancy": "45.9",
  "GNP": "5976.00",
  "GNPOld": "NULL",
  "LocalName": "Afganistan/Afqanestan",
  "GovernmentForm": "Islamic Emirate",
  "HeadOfState": "Mohammad Omar",
  "Capital": "1",
  "Code2": "AF"
},
{
```

**controller.js**

```
countryApp.controller('ctrlMain', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('world.json').success(function(data){
    $scope.world = data;
  });

  });

 countryApp.controller('detailsCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams){
$scope.name = $routeParams.countryName;
});
```

**all.html**

```
<td class="heading"><a href="" ng-click="reverse = predicate == 'LifeExpectancy' && !reverse; predicate = 'LifeExpectancy'">Befolkningsm&aumlngd</a></td>

<tr ng-repeat="country in world.Country | filter: { Continent: vDel } | filter:search | orderBy: predicate:reverse">
  <td>{{ country.Population }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: If its an option I'd change the JSON file. If your data is typed logically, then you should store it as typed data.

Comment: At minimum, type the data before you attach it to the scope.

Comment: I rather not change the json file since it's too massive :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do what you are looking for. The best way would be to update your JSON at the server. If that is not an option, this update to your ng-repeat will do the trick.

```
<tr ng-repeat="country in world.Country | filter:search | orderBy:'Population*1':reverse">
  <td>{{ country.Population | number}}</td>
</tr>
```

I have set up a plunker showing this working in the `orderBy`

http://plnkr.co/edit/ocD0TskHAqULHUddDPku?p=preview

EDIT: Updated plunker so reverse works.